# Hive SQL automatically round off

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am doing a multiplicate 3 columns  and it seems like automatically rounding of 6 decimal places. The type of my column is decimal(38, 10).
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5DLW.png

How can i show full 10 decimal places as result? Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: i couldnt recreate the scenario, but can you please try this SQL and let us know result? `select cast( cast(col_a as decimal(38,10)) * cast(col_b as decimal(38,10))* * cast(col_c as decimal(38,10)) as decimal(38,10))`? Explicit casting will give you better control and correct output

Comment: @KoushikRoy yeah, i tried but nothing change, the result similar than my query :((.
I mean that i want the result have 10 decimal places instead of 6.

Comment: can you give me your SQL with cast around all coulmns and result ?